# Node.js can not always get value from my config file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node.js in the server side. I have a RESTful service like;

```
app.get('/getAndroidVersion', function(req,res){res.json({version: config.androidVerion});});
```

This service must return version value from the config file. Although I am changing the `androidVerion` value in the config file node.js returns different value from the config value. For example in the config file version value is 2, but node.js returns 3.

After changing the version value in the config file I wrote a console.log statement before service call like that

```
app.get('/getAndroidVersion', function(req,res){console.log(config.androidVerion)    
   res.json({version: config.androidVerion});
});
```

It also writes different value from the config file to the console. What is the problem? Is node.js caches or return random values for the version number.

How can I handle this problem? Thank you.

Comment: add some code snippets will look into it

Comment: Did you restart the server after changes in config value?

Comment: Yes I restart but again does not return the value from config file . And I do not want to restart server because the system will be live and If I restart users can not reach the server a few second. It must always take value from the config file.

Comment: How is your config file imported in your code? Do you use `fs.readFile?` or are you `require()`-ing it?

Comment: var config = require('../conf');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calls to `require` are *cached*.

From [Node.js: Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) docs:

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

You got a lot of options here:

#### Use `fs.readFile` for each request to read from disk

You can use `readFile` instead of require, to read your config file from disk for every request. This ensures you always get the most up-to-date version of the file.

#### Store config in a database

If this is a high-traffic app you might want to keep those config settings in a database instead of a file. DB engines usually avoid touching the disk for [frequently executed queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548301/what-is-caching).

#### Write your own persisted object mechanism

Going a step further, you can just write your own mechanism for storing K/V pairs; This mechanism should persist to disk any changes to the object when setting a value whilst avoiding touching the disk when attempting to get a value.

Here's an (untested) example:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

class PersistedObject {
  constructor(path) {
    this.path = path
    this.obj = {}
  }

  load() {
    const json = fs.readFileSync(this.path, 'utf8')

    this.obj = json ? JSON.parse(json) : {}
  }

  set(key, value, cb) {
    this.obj[key] = value

    fs.writeFile(this.path, JSON.stringify(this.obj), cb)
  }

  get(key) {
    return this.obj[key]
  }
}

// Construct with a path to your config.json.
const config = new PersistedObject(path.resolve(__dirname, './config.json'))

// Load data from disk. Run this once on startup.
config.load()

// Calling `.set` sets the in-memory `obj`,
// and also persists the obj on disk.
config.set('firstName', 'Mary', (err, result) => {
  // Calls to `.get` use the in-memory `obj` and do not touch the disk.
  console.log(config.get('firstName')) // logs 'Mary'
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nicholas . I will try and inform you about the result

Comment: It is Ok now. I was trying for 3 days. Thank you so much